# converting a string to a line in a json file in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to write a json file. The json file should look something like this -

```
{
  "roster":[
    {"name":"Andy","age":11},
    {"name":"Nathan","age":10},
    {"name":"Amy","age":12}
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":2,"target":0,"value":8},
    {"source":3,"target":0,"value":10}
  ]
}
```

I am trying to create the roster part of the json by running through a for loop. In each iteration I am trying to append a line to the json file as follows -

```
wf = open("abc.json", "w")
wf.write('{\n"Roster":[\n')
for example in data:
    name = ----some code here ----
    group = ----some code here ----
    wf.write('{"name":"'+name+'","group":'+group+'},\n')
```

I am getting a typeError - str and int objects cannot be concatenated. I understand why I am getting that error. I was just wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Please please please DO NOT construct JSON by hand! Use the ``json`` module!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you really want to write the json by hand, then the way to get around the concatenation error is to simply typecast the number to a string:

```
wf.write('{"name" : "'+str(name)+'","group":'+str(group)'},\n')
```

It would definitely be advisable to use the json module in python, it's a pretty great library.

For example, to get the json example you gave us:

```
{
  "roster":[
    {"name":"Andy","age":11},
    {"name":"Nathan","age":10},
    {"name":"Amy","age":12}
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":2,"target":0,"value":8},
    {"source":3,"target":0,"value":10}
  ]
}
```

You could use the following:

import json

```
result = {}
result['roster'] = []
result['roster'].append({'name' : 'Andy', 'age' : 11})
result['roster'].append({'name' : 'Nathan', 'age' : 10})
result['roster'].append({'name' : 'Amy', 'age' : 12})
result['links'] = []
result['links'].append({'source' : 1, 'target' : 0, 'value' : 1})
...
```

(Obviously you would probably do this with a for loop instead of by hand in your program).
And then to convert this python dictionary to a json object you just use:

```
json.dumps(result)
```

Comment: This doesn't explain to the OP why they were getting the error.

Comment: OP Said they understand why they are getting the error, but were wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: @orange - I am not getting the following issue in the output file -
{"roster": ["{\"name\" : \"Andy\",\"age\":11},\n", "{\"name\" : \"Nathan\",\"age\":10},\. How to get rid of those extra double quotes outside the curly braces?

Comment: That looks like you might be passing in strings still to the list. The json module handles conversions completely from python dictionaries and lists to json format. So if you're doing a result['roster'].append("{'name : 'Andy', 'age' : 11}") with double quotes there it will just think it is a string and not treat it like a dictionary. Let me know if this is the case?

Comment: Yes that was the problem. I should have noticed that. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error:

```
 typeError - str and int objects cannot be concatenated
```

Because strings and integers cannot be concatenated.

Use [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) to cast the integer to a string for concatenation instead.

```
wf.write('{"name":"'+name+'","group":'+str(group)+'},\n')
```

**Or even better read up on [string formatting in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).**

**Or even more betterer read up on the [Python JSON module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).**

Answer (score 0):

Python is [Strongly Typed](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language) which means:

```
s = "foo"
s += 123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

If you are adding strings (*which btw are immutable*) you need to "cast" the `int` to a `str`:

```
s = "foo"
s += str(123)
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking your string. You have to ensure `string` concatenation.

Try:

```
'{"name":"'+str(name)+'","group":'+str(group)+'},\n'
```

Or use `json module` to support you to output json file easily.

```
import json

output = {}
output['roster'] = [
    {'name':'Andy', 'age':11},
    {'name': 'Nathan', 'age': 10}
]

print(json.dumps(output))
```

Output:

```
{"roster": [{"name": "Andy", "age": 11}, {"name": "Nathan", "age": 10}]}
```

Comment: This doesn't explain to the OP why they were getting the error.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr "I understand why I am getting that error. I was just wondering if there is a better way to do it."  The OP didn't want an explanation.  They wanted alternatives.  This answer is an alternative.